Topology of windings on the two-torus
In short my question is: what can we say about the quotient topology induced by the linear flow on a two-torus?
I know that an irrational slope leads to a dense winding and hence (if I'm not mistaken) the quotient topology is trivial.
But what about the case where the slope is rational? I know orbits are then homeomorphic to $S^1$ but I can't get my head around what the topology of the quotient space looks like.
Thank you.

If the slope is irrational, a keyword to search for is 'irrational torus'. I know that there are interesting works regarding the diffeological structure of the quotient space.

The quotient topology, by a linear flow of irrational slope, is the trivial topology on an uncountable set of the same cardinality as the reals.
When the slope is rational the quotient is much nicer; it is homeomorphic to $S^1$.
As a hint for the latter exercise: start with the case that the flow is horizontal and carefully produce a section (homeomorphic to the quotient).

Thanks for your answer Sam - regarding the irrational case: I am not sure to see how the quotient topology on the quotient space  be non-trivial (I can see why it's uncountable), which subsets of the quotient would have an open pre-image on T2?

As far as I understand, the quotient space is topologically trivial when the slope is irrational. It should follow from this exercise: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226618/show-that-g-h-has-the-trivial-topology-if-h-subset-g-is-dense

I assumed that “trivial” meant “trivial space”.  I will rephrase.

Thanks guys (and yes I was talking about the quotient topology indeed).

In the irrational case, since an equivalence class on $T^2$ is the same thing as an orbit of the flow, the question "Which subsets of the quotient would have an open pre-image on $T^2$?" is more-or-less the same as the question "Which open subsets $U \subset T^2$ are unions of flow orbits?". The answer is: only $\emptyset$ or $T^2$, because if $T^2-U \ne \emptyset$ then $U$ is one of those sets if and only if $T^2-U$ is a dense closed set.
